# str_replace for dynamic string content?

Tags: php, wildcard, str-replace

I have this scenario of 200 over webpage in different language, all with this ending format.

```
<script>alert("***** ATENCIÓN ***** \n\n Es posible .");</script>
</body>


<script>alert("***** ATTENTION ***** \n\n Click now .");</script>
</body>
```

I want to dynamically replace

```
<script>alert("***** ATENCIÓN ***** \n\n Es posible .");</script>
</body>
```

to become `</body>` only.

```
<script>alert("***** ATTENTION ***** \n\n Click now .");</script>
</body>
```

to become `</body>` only.

the common pattern is

```
<script>alert("    ");</script>
</body>
```

since there's dynamic multi language content inside the javascript alert, I cannot directly use str_replace, have to do some wildcard kind of mapping ....

any idea how to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

read up on [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

E.g.,

```
$pattern = '/<script>alert[^<]*<\/script>\s*<\/body>\s*$/';
$cleanedBody = preg_replace($pattern, '</body>', $body);
```

Comment: what if the content doesn't tie to ending </body>?    this way? 
$contents = preg_replace('/<script>[^<]*<\/script>\s*\s$/', '', $contents);

Comment: sure, that will remove all scripts that do not contain a less-than sign, but will remove only part of a script that does (producing broken html)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using regex and preg_replace

```
$pat = '/<script>alert\(("\** [\p{L}]* \** [^)]*)\);<\/script>/u';
$nestr = preg_replace($pat, '</body>', $html);
```

You can see the regex working [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/sX5eN8/1)